# How to upload certificate files in HyperLedger Fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, smartcontracts

I'm now learning about the Oracle Platform's Hyperledger Fabric.

I also want to validate a specific product. For example, let's say I have two organizations: a client organization and a duck farm organization. If a customer plans to purchase duck meat, they want to know if it's healthy for them. I would like to "confirm" that the duck is good using a certification file at the point in the process where the duck meat is being processed.

Therefore, I have a question on how to upload certificate files (such as PDFs) on HyperLedger Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a chaincode that puts a key->value pair via a `PutState` function where the key is a name and the value is the bytes representation of the PDF.

Check out [this](https://kctheservant.medium.com/putstate-and-getstate-the-api-in-chaincode-dealing-with-the-state-in-the-ledger-part-1-2008d6a86f98) link and [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html) one.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take in order to upload certificate files or proof in Hyperledger Fabric.

1. Serialize the PDF file into a byte array or Base64 String and insert it using `stub.putState(key, PDFBytes)`. This approach will provide proof of PDF document right from the blockchain itself. However, this approach is discouraged because it will increase the size of your ledger and possibly add additional stress to your blockchain network.
2. Keep the PDF files in a file server. Caclculate the Hash such as MD5 checksum of your PDF files, and add only the hash and a URL to locate the file from the server to the ledger. This approach will provide only proof of existence of the PDF file. The legitimacy of the file can be proven using the checksum of the file, while not adding additional overhead on your Blockchain network.

Comment: It's better to not use MD5, but something else like SHA2 or SHA3 
https://github.com/corkami/collisions

Comment: I believe I comprehended; I'll try! I'm grateful.